# How to add a new button in Main Activity after user clicks a button from a Popup?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm developing an Android app on my free time to learn about Android development. I'm trying to make a Grade/GPA Calculator App. I currently have a button called *"+ New Semester"* whose purpose is to open a popup where the user inputs the semester name. This can be seen in the following two images:

[image]
[image]

User clicks on "+ New Semester" and the popup appears prompting the user to add the name of that semester.

Now, what I want to do is that when the user clicks on the *"Done"* button a new button with the text that the user typed in into the text box is created below the *"+ New Semester"* button,  but I can't figure out how to do it. I would appreciate any help.

This is the code I currently have:

```
package com.example.gradecalculator;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Private Fields
    private Dialog d;
    private ImageButton newSemesterButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        d = new Dialog(this);
    }

    // When user clicks on "+ New Semester" button open a popup where the user is prompted to
    // type in the Semester Name and when "Done" is clicked the new semester appears in the view
    public void newSemesterPopup(View v) {
        TextView closePopup;
        ImageButton doneButton;

        d.setContentView(R.layout.new_semester_popup);

        doneButton = (ImageButton) d.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMainActivity();
            }
        });

        closePopup = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
        closePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });
        d.show();
    }

    // Open Main Activity
    public void openMainActivity() {
        Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by first getting the reference to the layout where you want to add your button. Lets say, the name of the layout where your button should be has the name **btn_layout**,

1. Bind the layout. (i.e. LinearLayout layout = findViewById (R.id.btn_layout); )
2. When the DONE button is clicked, create your new button and add it to the layout. For example:

> ```
>  LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
>                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
>                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
>         Button  btn = new Button(this);
>         btn.setText("Your text from edittext");
>         layout.addView(btn, params);
> ```

Even better if you can declare the Button and Layout as fields

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the reference from your buttons parent layout. then create a button and add it to the view. Something like this:

```
public void newSemesterPopup(View v) {
    TextView closePopup;
    ImageButton doneButton;

    d.setContentView(R.layout.new_semester_popup);

    doneButton = (ImageButton) d.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openMainActivity();
        }
    });

    closePopup = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
    closePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           myParentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
          params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) new 
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           yourEditText = d.findViewById(R.id.YourEditText);
           myNewButton = new Button(this);
           String buttonText = yourEditText.text.toString();
           myNewButton.setText(buttonText); 
           myParentLayout.addView(myNewButton, params);

            d.dismiss();
        }
    });
    d.show();
}
```

Comment: I guess that the problem there would be that I would want to add more than just 1 button since it would depend on the user, would this take care of that too? Thank you! @Mateo Hervas

Comment: Just edited the answer to an approach where you can keep on adding buttons. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it tomorrow, do you mind if I ask you if I have any further doubts? I appreciate the help!

Comment: Sure! just let me know and I will do what I can to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just make that new button on main screen and set visibility to false = `newButton.setVisibility(false);`
and if you press button done on popup just set visibility to true hope that will help, not sure if that's what you mean

Comment: It's more or less what I mean. The only problem is that there will be x amount of those buttons because it will depend on the user so there might only be one button or there might be 20 buttons

Comment: make boolean array for example boolean[] newButton = new boolean[MAX_BUTTONS] and make global int newButtonCount and everytime user will press done on popup each boolean will change like
if(pressed done)
newButton[newButtonCount] = true;
newButtonCount++;